# Removing multi-line string from a filed in a file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file as below which is sent by source system and they have no processing mechanism from their end except to add columns:

```
1,"Bob Smith
531 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC",3,4,"qqqqzzzz" 
5,"Bob Smith
531 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC",6,7,"qqqqzzzz"
```

Expected output:

```
1,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",3,4
5,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",6,7
```

I have tried below approach:

1. Requested source system to add a identified at the end of each line "qqqqzzzz"
2. Tried to replace all the new line with space and then again replace all qqqqzzzz with new line

But the last replace of qqqqzzzz results in new line replacement with quotes which breaks into next line as below:

```
1,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",3,4,"" 
5,"Bob Smith

sed '/^$/d' all.csv|tr '\n' ' '|sed 's/qqqqzzzz/\n/g' >results.csv
```

Tried for the solution of replacing the quoted text [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187889/how-do-i-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-using-sed),[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162377/sed-remove-the-very-last-occurrence-of-a-string-a-comma-in-a-file?rq=1) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/removing-multiple-lines-from-cell-data-in-a-csv-file-4175538718/)

Update after trying with command:

```
$ sed 'N;N;s/\n//g;s/,"qqqqzzzz"$//' quotetest.csv
1,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",3,4,"qqqqzzzz"
5,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",6,7
```

Comment: Don't insert `<br>` in code sections, indent each line by 4-spaces

Comment: sure, will take care of it from next time.

Comment: sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything more complicated, including anything involving multi-line records, you should not even consider using sed as an awk solution will always be more robust, efficient, simpler, clearer, easier to enhance, etc... Chances are you didn't need to add that qqqqzzzz string and there was a simpler solution based on just `\r\n` line endings or ignoring newlines within quotes.

Comment: @EdMorton: Since i wasn't aware of methods i requested adding 'qqqqzzzz', please guide how we can proceed without that will try to implement that

Comment: You already accepted an answer to this question. If you have a new question, then post that new question separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=",\"qqqqzzzz\" ?\r?\n"}{$1=$1}1' file
1,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",3,4
5,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",6,7
```

Tested with dos and unix line endings. The key was to use the identifier and related extra characters (comma, conditional space and line ending characters) as record separator (`RS`) and the problem was to se there was a space after the first identifier but not after the second.

Comment: Output: 
1,"Bob Smith  531 Pennsylvania Avenue  Washington, DC",3,4,"qqqqzzzz"  5,"Bob Smith  531 Pennsylvania Avenue  Washington, DC",6,7

Comment: comes in one single line rather than two separate lines

Comment: I added a space before the line ending. Would that help?

Comment: Now the last line is displayed as "5,"Bob Smith 531 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington, DC",6,7,"qqqqzzzz""

Comment: Made the space conditional, how about now?

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how the command works in detail?